# Add more Images by php form

Tags: php

I want to prepare 5 photo upload form and user need to select all 5 photo at once and the submit the form
then i need to store all 5 photos in the Target Directory by renaming image as "1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg". I stored only one image but after add For loop for save more than one file its not working ....please support.

// Image Upload FORM

```
<form action="saveinntion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <h1>Upload Your Innovation</h1
    <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">4</span>Upload Images</legend>

        <input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" > 
        </br>
        <input type="file" name="img2" id="img2"> 
        </br>
        <input type="file" name="img3" id="img3"> 
        </br>
        <input type="file" name="img4" id="img4"> 
        </br>
        <input type="file" name="img5" id="img5">
        </br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

saveinntion.php file

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");
$target_dir = "Upload/";
$img=$_POST['img'];

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['$img[]']["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($_FILES['$img[]']["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG &  JPEG files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['$img[]']["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['$img[]']["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
header("Location: upload1.php?id=$msg");
?>
```

Comment: You can make an array. And set every HTML field on required.

Comment: And this code really works for the first image? I'd be quite surprised, since you reference your `$_POST['img']` and in your form nothing is called "img".

Comment: $img=$_POST['img1']; added but not solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your naming. as @Twinfriends said in the command it is highly unlikely to upload any file

replace **$_FILES['$img[]']** with $_FILES['img'.($i+1)] in your code.

line # 5

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['img'.($i+1)]["name"]);
```

line #13

```
if ($_FILES['img'.($i+1)]["size"] > 500000) {
```

line #25

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img'.($i+1)]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['img'.($i+1)]["name"]). " has been   uploaded.";
```

To renaming file.

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES['img'.($i+1)]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
$target_file = $target_dir . ($i+1).".".$imageFileType;
```

Comment: in my solution there is no need for $img variable. as i think i have replace all of them with ** 'img'.($i+1) **

Comment: can put  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); above the page and see what the error you are getting.

Comment: why @SaidbakR? i think i wrote the code according to to the current html.

Comment: $i started in the for loop with 0 but in html first one is  img1. this is why i put $i+1 :D

Comment: Happy to help. 

Comment: @reza    thaxx for your grate support..;)

Comment: @raza      could you please support me to rename the images as 1 to 5 when storeing the derectory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131562/discussion-between-gayan-chaturanga-and-reza).

Comment: @reza     rename codes not worked....after replace rename code....didn't add images to directory

Comment: @GayanChaturanga my bad. one variable name was missing. corrected now. : D

Comment: @reza      thaxxx.......now it corrected with your new codes....with replacement of $i instead of $i+1